# Checking should have a controller defined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I am checking whether in my module `PracticeCtrl` exists. I written following test for this.

Gives me error : `ReferenceError: myApp is not defined`

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    describe('Controller: PracticeCtrl', function () {            

      // load the controller's module
        beforeEach(function () {
            // Load the controller's module
            module('myApp');    
        });

        it('should have a PracticeCtrl controller', function() {
            expect(myApp.PracticeCtrl).toBeDefined();
        });    

    });
});
```

How to check in my module a controller exists? As i am new for this, have less knowledge on syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe("SomeControllerTest", function () {
    var scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('SomeController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it("should be defined", function () {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```